# Opening system settings freezes the machine on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: settings

I have just installed Ubuntu 17.10 (Artful Aardvark) on my machine. When opening system settings, the machine just freezes up. Is there anything I can do to fix this problem?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried to diagnose the problem? Have you tried running any hardware diagnostics? Or booted from a minimal boot image and run any single user mode diagnostics? When you say the machine freezes up, what's showing on the output device? Can you soft reset the system or do you have to power cycle it?

Comment: This looks like it might belong in AskUbuntu

Comment: I have re-installed many times, and in all of that somehow, the problem went away. The last install was exactly the same as the first install .. connected to the internet and took updates during install

Comment: But what happens is that the mouse disappears and the desktop becomes completely frozen. The only thing I can do is keep the power button to switch off the machine, nothing else works

Comment: I don't have Nvidia, I have Intel Graphics. Settings only freeze when I open them when I'm connected to the external dock with extra monitors and stuff. Any suggestions at where to look at (I'm using Wayland)?

Comment: @PaoloMioni I've got Intel Graphics too (520), and also have issues opening the System Settings when connected to external monitors.So far my workaround has been to unplug all external monitors, open System Settings, and then plug the monitors back in. Not ideal but it seems to work!

Answer (score 3):

Doing this in terminal, you're gonna reset control center (worked for me):

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/control-center/
```

Answer (score 0):

I purged and reinstalled my nVidia drivers and then it worked.

[Ubuntu 17.10 freezes when trying to open settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46887975/ubuntu-17-10-freezes-when-trying-to-open-settings/46888065#46888065][1])