# Ubuntu 17.10 freezes when trying to open settings

Tags: ubuntu

I reinstalled ubuntu 17.10 twice now, and both times whenever I try to open settings, gnome tweaks, display settings the system freezes up. 
`I tried reinstalling nvidia drivers`, since someone suggested it might be a problem - didn't work. 
`Tried to disable all my gnome extensions` - didn't work.

If it freezes up, I can operate my keyboard(Caps Lock light is toggling) and I can operate my mouse(It moves), but nothing else works, I can only kill my computer by holding down the power button.

[settings freezes machine on Ubuntu 17.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46869449/settings-freezes-machine-on-ubuntu-17-10)
same problem here, but he managed to resolve it by reinstalling multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was still with nVidia drivers. After my second clean install I purged and reinstalled my nVidia drivers and now everything works.